# How to append the data to a file which is stored in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, reduce

I want to store the details of current running queries, like file Names on which the queries are executing and time. for this i created one file in HDFS, tried to writing the information. But the problem is how to append the data to the existing file. Please help me. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

First of all stop all the Hadoop daemons and add the following property in your **hdfs-site.xml** :

```
<property>
       <name>dfs.support.append</name>
       <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Now, restart the daemons and try this code :

```
public class HDFSAppend {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.addResource(new Path("/path/to/your/hadoop/directory/conf/core-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(new Path("/path/to/your/hadoop/directory/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        FSDataOutputStream out = fs.append(new Path("/demo.txt"));
        out.writeUTF("Append demo...");
        fs.close();

    }    
}
```

HTH

Comment: going by [hdfs defaults for hadoop-2.4.1 onwards](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml), the dfs.support.append property is by-default true, doesn't need to be set explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from the command line:

```
$ hadoop fs -appendToFile <local_file> <hdfs_file>
```

If you are using java see this question:
[Write a file in hdfs with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000840/write-a-file-in-hdfs-with-java)

Comment: I'm using java and i used the same code given in the link. But the problem is i'm unable to append the data to the file, which is already created.

Comment: As Tariq suggested, you need to set the dfs.support.append property.
See this link for more info [link](http://hadoop4mapreduce.blogspot.com/2012/08/two-methods-to-append-content-to-file.html)

Comment: @B.J.Smegma not anymore. dfs.support.append defaults to true going by [hadoop-2.4.1 hdfs defaults](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing it from command line would be:

```
echo -e 'Hello\nWorld' | hadoop dfs -put - /1.txt
```

Which will create a file `1.txt` in the path `/` of `HDFS` and will store two lines `Hello\nWorld` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Use command :
hdfs dfs -put *file_location* *hdfs_location*

### Heading

Note: hdfs_location is enable

Answer (score 0):

Solved..!!

Append is supported in HDFS.

You just have to do some configurations and simple code as shown below :

**Step 1:** set dfs.support.append as true in hdfs-site.xml :

```
<property>
   <name>dfs.support.append</name>
   <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Stop all your daemon services using stop-all.sh and restart it again using start-all.sh

**Step 2 (Optional):** Only If you have a singlenode cluster , so you have to set replication factor to 1 as below :

Through command line :

```
./hdfs dfs -setrep -R 1 filepath/directory
```

Or you can do the same at run time through java code:

```
fShell.setrepr((short) 1, filePath);
```

**Step 3 :** Code for Creating/appending data into the file :

```
public void createAppendHDFS() throws IOException {
    Configuration hadoopConfig = new Configuration();
    hadoopConfig.set("fs.defaultFS", hdfsuri);
    FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(hadoopConfig);
    String filePath = "/test/doc.txt";
    Path hdfsPath = new Path(filePath);
    fShell.setrepr((short) 1, filePath); 
    FSDataOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    try {
        if (fileSystem.exists(hdfsPath)) {
            fileOutputStream = fileSystem.append(hdfsPath);
            fileOutputStream.writeBytes("appending into file. \n");
        } else {
            fileOutputStream = fileSystem.create(hdfsPath);
            fileOutputStream.writeBytes("creating and writing into file\n");
        }
    } finally {
        if (fileSystem != null) {
            fileSystem.close();
        }
        if (fileOutputStream != null) {
            fileOutputStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly let me know for any other help.

Cheers.!!