# Capture Output for Oozie Spark Action

Tags: pyspark, cloudera, oozie, oozie-workflow

I am running Oozie Spark action in cloudera and I need a way to capture the stdout of oozie spark action and store in HDFS

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44171000/capture-console-output-of-spark-action-node-in-oozie-as-variable-across-the-oozi

Comment: Hi The solution Provided is in Scala , I am looking for a workout in python with spark