# Content not saved in file while spark job running on cluster (yarn)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am facing a weird issue and I've stuck with that for a while.

Basically in my spark application I have a method, where I create a file in MapR fs and save some content in this file.

The method is like below:

```
    def collector(value: String): Unit = {
        val conf = new Configuration()
        val fs= FileSystem.get(conf)
        val path = getConfig("path")
        Try {fs.create(new Path(path + s"${scala.util.Random.alphanumeric take 10 mkString}" +
          Calendar.getInstance.getTimeInMillis))
          .write(value.getBytes); 
          fs.close()}.getOrElse(logger.warn("File not saved"))
      }
```

This method is called from different object. When I run it with --master local[*], then the file is created in specific location in the FS with string that is passed in **value**. However, when I run it on cluster (--master yarn), then only empty file is saved. When I print **value**, its printing the string. But for some reason not saving it in the file.

I wonder if anybody has any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: This has most probably nothing to do with your problem, but using `System.currentTimeMillis` seems to return the same as `Calendar.getInstance.getTimeInMillis`, but without any mention of the `Calendar` legacy api.

Comment: I found something similar here:
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952121/can-i-write-a-plain-text-hdfs-or-local-file-from-a-spark-program-not-from-an> maybe it will help.