# save output over Scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I executed one simple SQL query and wanted to save the output as a text file on my server. It started to run for almost 3 days and nothing happened.
Can you say what is the problem? Or maybe what other codes can I use to save and measure the run time of queries over spark scala?

```
val in = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("mytablename.csv")
in.registerTempTable("mytablename")
val dn = spark.sql("select * from mytablename").show(10)
val df = spark.time(df.show(10))
df.write.text("file://hadoop/location/text.txt")
```

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952121/can-i-write-a-plain-text-hdfs-or-local-file-from-a-spark-program-not-from-an) useful?

Comment: What is your Spark master? Did you open the SparkUI and see why it might be stuck? For example, do you have enough resources to start the executors?

Comment: it is spark-shell.