# Spark: How to serialize/deserialize java objects and distribute them in nodes

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have some java objects saved on HDFS to be used by various spark jobs. I know that for local filesystem we can deserialize using `ObjectInputStream` class. But till now I am unable to find any way to do it on remote file systems (HDFS?) using spark.

**Update**: spark context has an api: `objectFile` to get an object. Object could be collected as:-

```
JavaRDD<Map<Long, BloomFilter>> obj = context.objectFile("/user/hdfs/path");
dat = obj.collect().get(0);
```

But now I ran into related problem. `dat` object will be populated only by the node to receive the RDD. But this data needs to be used by all the nodes in spark. I know there is a `Broadcast` function but that means shipping my data to all the nodes and data being very big in size will defeat the purpose of map reduce. Is there any better way to deserialize and distribute objects in a spark environment.

Comment: Could somebody tell what is wrong with the question? Why the close vote?

Answer (score 0):

In Spark the [`SparkContext`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html) is usually used to read in data in a distributed way and Spark should handle the deserialization for you. Particularly the method [`objectFile`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#objectFile(java.lang.String,%20int,%20scala.reflect.ClassTag)) looks like it could be of help.

Writing a file in HDFS is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000840/write-a-file-in-hdfs-with-java).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please see the update. I am now using objectFile call but there is another related problem!

Comment: Your `obj` variable represents the data as it is distributed. That is the whole point of Spark. You can perform distributed operations on `obj` by calling transformations like `map` or actions like `reduce` on it. (`collect` is also an action but after calling it you are dealing with a non-distributed object)

Comment: Obj will be distributed between nodes which I will collect at the driver using collect function (dat object), but I need the complete dat object present at every node. Its an HashMap to be used by all the nodes for processing.

Comment: A broadcast will do what you want, but the whole idea behind Spark is to work on distributed datasets. You might want to rethink your tool choice. Also you wouldn't read in the data using `SparkContext` when you intent to broadcast it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

in spark ,use deserializeobject  ,let text to clickhouse