# Write to separate files in Apache Spark (with Java)

Tags: java, apache-spark, hdfs

I am reading my data as whole text files. My object is of type `Article` which I defined. Here's the reading and processing of the data:

```
JavaPairRDD<String, String> filesRDD = context.wholeTextFiles(inputDataPath);
JavaRDD<Article> processingFiles = filesRDD.map(fileNameContent -> {
    String content = fileNameContent._2();
    Article a = new Article(content);
    return a;
}
```

Now, once every file has been processed separately, I would like to write the result on HDFS as a separate file to, not with `saveAsTextFile`. I know that probably I have to do it with `foreach`, so:

```
processingFiles.foreach(a -> {
     // Here is a pseudo code of how I want to do this
     String fileName = here_is_full_file_name_to_write_to_hdfs;
     writeToDisk(fileName, a); // This could be a simple text file
});
```

Any ideas how to do this in Java?

Comment: Have you tried using the standard java IO to open the file, write the contents to that file, and then close the file within the foreach? (This may give you a serialization error, but if it works you're done.)

Comment: u can look at using HDFS file system APIs . Refer [stackoverflow answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000840/write-a-file-in-hdfs-with-java)

Comment: Have you looked at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995040/write-to-multiple-outputs-by-key-spark-one-spark-job?