# Scala - How to Call REST API and save as json file in HDFS?

Tags: json, scala, rest, apache-spark, hdfs

Environment: Scala and spark 1.6

I am trying to -
1. getting json data through Rest API call
2. write in HDFS as json file 
3. Convert json file into dataframe

```
val rawdata = "curl http://services.groupkt.com/state/get/USA/all"!!
println(rawdata)  // can see json output, but can't save as file in HDFS
```

I can see output on screen, but how can I write contents of rawdata to hdfs url (hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/test/)? Or is there any way to purse content of rawdata without saving as file? I also need to convert json to dataframe.

Thanks in advance
Hossain

Comment: Pleas ad a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val rawdata = "curl http://services.groupkt.com/state/get/USA/all"!!
println(rawdata)
```

Once you have the `data`, you can use the code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17819581/5019163) to save it in `Hadoop`.

> Creating Dataframe:

Suppose your json string is something like this:

```
{"time":"sometext1","host":"somehost1","event":  {"category":"sometext2","computerName":"somecomputer1"}}
```

you can convert the `json into dataframe` from the following code:

```
// Creating Rdd    
val vals = sc.parallelize(
  """{"time":"sometext1","host":"somehost1","event":  {"category":"sometext2","computerName":"somecomputer1"}}""" ::
    Nil)

// Creating Schema   
val schema = (new StructType)
  .add("time", StringType)
  .add("host", StringType)
  .add("event", (new StructType)
    .add("category", StringType)
    .add("computerName", StringType))

import sqlContext.implicits._
val jsonDF = sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json(vals)
```

After creating `dataframe` you can still have an option to save it in `hadoop` by using [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) lib or by using `saveAsTextFile` method on **RDD**.