# Spark write the file inside the worker process

Tags: caching, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-1.6

I have a Spark job that is generating a set of results with statistics. My number of work items are more than slave count. So I am doing more than one processing per slave.

I `cache` results after generating `RDD` objects to be able to reuse them as I have multiple write operations: one for result objects and another for statistics. Both write operations use `saveAsHadoopFile`.

Without caching Spark reruns the job again per each write operation and that is taking a long time and redoing the same execution twice (more if I had more writes).

With caching I am hitting the memory limit. Some of previously calculated results are lost during caching and I am seeing `"CacheManager:58 - Partition rdd_1_0 not found, computing it"` messages. Spark eventually goes into an infinite loop as it tries to cache more results while losing some others.

I am aware of the fact that Spark has different storage levels for caching. Using memory + disk would solve our problem. But I am wondering whether we can write down files right in the worker without generating `RDD` objects or not. I am not sure if that is possible though. Is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that writing files inside a Spark worker process is not different than writing a file in a Java process. Write operation just requires just creating functionality to serialize and save files to HDFS. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000840/write-a-file-in-hdfs-with-java) has several answers on how to do it.

`saveAsHadoopFile` is just a convenient way of doing it.