# Setting number of partitions while writing a file to HDFS in Java

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

Referring to this question, [Write a file in hdfs with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000840/write-a-file-in-hdfs-with-java), i am able to write the file to `HDFS`, but the output file has only one partition. How to set number of partitions that output file is going to contain?

Comment: You can use partitioner for this...

Comment: What do you mean by partitions? Give an example

Comment: partitions?, Number of splits that a HDFS file is distributed into, or the number of part files it has.